# Presumed misusage of Fubini's theorem

Tags: proof-verification, partial-differential-equations, fourier-transform

As a physicist sometimes I do operations without checking if the conditions to do such operations are satisfied. Most of the times all functions that we interact with are very well-behaved so it goes well. This time though I wanted to check because this operations seems a little bit fishy.

What I wanted to evaluate was the following integral

$$
\int_{\mathbb R}\int_0^t e^{ikx}e^{-Dk^2(t-t')}f(x,t')\delta(k)\,\mathrm dt'\,\mathrm dk
$$

where

$$
f(x,t) =\begin{cases}1&0<t<\tau \\ 0 &t>\tau\end{cases}
$$

I've got this integral as part of the solution of the heat equation PDE with an external force $f(x,t)$, doing a Fourier transform and then anti-transforming.

To evaluate it **I've changed the oder of integration** to get rid of the Dirac delta which simplifies a lot the calculation

$$
\int_0^t\int_{\mathbb R} e^{ikx}e^{-Dk^2(t-t')}f(x,t')\delta(k)\,\mathrm dk\,\mathrm dt' = \int_0^t f(x,t')\,\mathrm dt'
$$

and proceded to evaluate my solution for the PDE.

> **Question:** Is this operation allowed? Does the function satisfie the requests of Fubini's theorem?

Comment: The Dirac Delta is not a function, it is a distribution, and the operation of interest is not an integral, it is a linear functional.  So, Fubini's Theorem does not apply.

Comment: @MarkViola That's clear. But what about the operation in itself, is that allowed?

Comment: Does $f$ really not depend on $x$ at all? Or is that a mistake?

Comment: @DisintegratingByParts Nope, it's not a mistake. On my problem sheet is written as $f(x,t)$ even if it depends only on $t$ (because there are multiple questions where $f$ changes while the general equation stays the same). I wrote it just for completion but clearly it can be wrote as $f(t)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it directly,
$$
    \int_0^t \int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{ikx}e^{-Dk^2(t-t')}\delta(k)dk f(t')dt'
   = \int_0^t 1\cdot f'(t')dt' \\
    \int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(\int_{0}^{t}e^{-Dk^2(t-t')}f(t')dt'\right) e^{ikx}\delta(k)dk=
   \left.\int_{0}^{t}e^{-Dk^2(t-t')}f(t')dt' \right|_{k=0}
$$
It looks like it works out just fine.

Comment: That's amazing! Thank you so much